# Find the columns values connectivity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table with sample data:

Table: `tbl_nodes`

```
create table tbl_nodes
(
    nod1 varchar(50),
    nod2 varchar(50),
    nod_lenght float
);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into tbl_nodes values('A','B',1600); 
insert into tbl_nodes values('G','H',45000);
insert into tbl_nodes values('B','C',2300);
insert into tbl_nodes values('C','D',2640);
insert into tbl_nodes values('B','D',2840);
insert into tbl_nodes values('C','E',2940);
insert into tbl_nodes values('D','F',2340);
insert into tbl_nodes values('M','N',9000);
insert into tbl_nodes values('E','A',100000);
```

**Expected Result**:

```
Connectivity        Total_Length
----------------------------------
A-B-C-D-F           8880
A-B-C-E-A           106840
A-B-D-F             6780
```

**Note**: I am trying to find out the nodes connectivity and sum of the length between the nodes.

I tried the following query for the same:

**My try**:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT nod1,nod2 ,sum(nod_lenght) as Total_length
    from tbl_nodes T1
    where EXISTS (select 1 from tbl_nodes T2 where T1.nod2 =T2.nod1) OR 
    EXISTS (select 1 from tbl_nodes T3 WHERE T1.nod1 =T3.nod2)
    GROUP BY nod1,nod2 
)
SELECT STUFF((select '-'+ case when c1.nod2 = c2.nod1 then c1.nod1 else c2.nod2 end
              from CTE c1 
              where c1.nod2 =c2.nod1 or c1.nod1 =c2.nod2
              for xml path('')),1,1,''),Total_length
FROM CTE c2
```

Unable to get the expected result.

Comment: Can you explain your expected results please? Why are there 3 different rows for A/B? it looks like hierarchical data, but if it is, which row does `A/B` join to where there are 2 rows for `B`? Which `B` does `A/B` join to, where there are 2 rows for `B` ? It also looks like you have a circular reference: `A`->`B`->`C`->`E`->`A`->`B`->`C`->`E`->`A`->...

Comment: @Larnu, My bad, Corrected the sample data.

Comment: That new data dosen't answer any of my questions. You didn't answer if it is hierarchical, and if it is there are *still* 2 rows for `B` (and `C`), and there is still a circular reference.

Comment: @Larnu, No its not a hierarchical data at all, Any nodes gets have connectivity with any one. I just need to find out the connectivity from source `A` to end node's `F` and `A` (Here end node `A` used as circular reference) .

Comment: So I go back to my original statement *"Can you explain your expected results please?"* You haven't explained your logic, and we aren't mind readers I'm afraid. You're question is going to be read by people who have no knowledge of you, or your system. We need to be both educated on the data you have, the data you want, ***and*** the logic implemented to get from A to B. Without that, we can't help you, as we don't know what it is you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need a recursive CTE.  However, your sample results doesn't make sense.

The following basically does what you want:

```
with cte AS (
      select nod1, nod2, nod_length as Total_length,
             convert(varchar(max), concat('-', nod1, '-', nod2, '-')) as nodes, 1 as lev
      from tbl_nodes n
      where nod1 = 'A'
      union all
      select cte.nod1, n.nod2, cte.Total_length + n.nod_length,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(cte.nodes, n.nod2, '-')) as nodes, lev + 1
      from cte join
           tbl_nodes n
           on cte.nod2 = n.nod1
      where nodes not like concat('%-', n.nod2, '-%') 
     )
select nodes, total_length
from cte
where not exists (select 1
                  from cte cte2
                  where cte2.nodes like concat(cte.nodes, '_%')
                 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aac830d39b740a20919f4522ce09ebcc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Works fine, Can you tune query? Its keep running for `4000` records.

Comment: @MAK . . . Unfortunately, there is little you can do other than have indexes on `nod1`.  You must have a wide tree if this is running for a long time.  I suspect you have an incredibly large result set.

Comment: Can you help me out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832990/performance-tuning-on-inner-join-with-between-condition