# Find only self referencing values using recursive query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Table**:

```
create table tbl_nodess
(
    nod1 varchar(50),
    nod2 varchar(50)
);
```

**Records**:

```
insert into tbl_nodess values('A','B'); 
insert into tbl_nodess values('B','C');
insert into tbl_nodess values('C','B');
insert into tbl_nodess values('D','E');
insert into tbl_nodess values('E','F');
insert into tbl_nodess values('G','H');
insert into tbl_nodess values('B','D');
insert into tbl_nodess values('D','A');
insert into tbl_nodess values('I','J');
insert into tbl_nodess values('J','K');
insert into tbl_nodess values('K','L');
insert into tbl_nodess values('L','J');
```

**Expected Result**:

```
self_ref_nodes 
------------------
A-B-C-B 
A-B-D-A
I-J-K-L-J
```

Explanation about expected result: I want to find only those nodes which are self referencing.

Example:

1. node `A` referring `B`, 
       `B` referring `C`,
       `C` referring `B`

The node `C` again referring to node `B`.

2. node `A` referring `B`, 
       `B` referring `D`,
       `D` referring `A`

The node `D` again referring to node `A`.

3. node `I` referring `J`, `J` referring `K`, `K` referring `L`, `L` referring `J`

The node `L` again referring to node `J`(which is already in the chain).

Query:

```
;with cte AS (
      select nod1, nod2, 
             convert(varchar(max), ('-'+ nod1+ '-'+ nod2+ '-')) as nodes, 1 as lev
      from tbl_nodess n
      where not exists(select 1 from tbl_nodess n1 where n.nod1 = n1.nod2)
      union all
      select cte.nod1, n.nod2, 
             convert(varchar(max), (cte.nodes+ n.nod2+ '-')) as nodes, lev + 1
      from cte join
           tbl_nodess n
           on cte.nod2 = n.nod1
      where nodes not like ('%-'+ n.nod2+ '-%') 
     )
select nodes
from cte
where not exists 
(select 1
from cte cte2
where cte2.nodes like (cte.nodes+ '_%'))
```

Comment: You have circular references here; that's a problem. Also,isn't this what you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319128/find-the-columns-values-connectivity

Comment: Another problem is that there's no definitive way to identify the root nodes. I would steer clear of such a data structure in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a crack at this, but I had to make some major assumptions.  First I stuck your data into a table variable:

```
DECLARE @tbl_nodess TABLE (nod1 VARCHAR(50), nod2 VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('A','B'); 
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('B','C');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('C','B');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('D','E');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('E','F');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('G','H');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('B','D');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('D','A');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('I','J');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('J','K');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('K','L');
INSERT INTO @tbl_nodess VALUES('L','J');
```

Then I wrote a recursive query:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        t.nod1,
        t.nod2,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), t.nod1 + '-' + t.nod2) AS accumulator,
        0 AS done
    FROM
        @tbl_nodess t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.nod1,
        t.nod2,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), x.accumulator + '-' + t.nod2) AS accumulator,
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(t.nod2, x.accumulator) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS done
    FROM
        x
        INNER JOIN @tbl_nodess t ON t.nod1 = x.nod2
    WHERE
        x.done = 0)
SELECT
    accumulator AS self_ref_nodes
FROM
    x
WHERE
    done = 1;
```

So how does this work?

I have the recursive query, using the "X - Y -> Y - Z" rule.  I also accumulate the chain, starting with nod1 - nod2, then adding any "new" nod2 when I find a match.

If I hit a loop then I want to stop, but I don't want to stop immediately.  I want to stop on the next loop, so I use the "done" to handle this.  I set it, and then stop when it's set to 1 on the next run through the recursion.

This prevents circular references, but if there were more elements then you might eventually hit the 100 limit.

It's also worth noting that I find a LOT of self-referencing loops, more than in your example:

```
L-J-K-L
K-L-J-K
J-K-L-J
I-J-K-L-J
D-A-B-D
D-A-B-C-B
B-D-A-B
C-B-C
C-B-D-A-B
B-C-B
A-B-D-A
A-B-C-B
```

Comment: So can you explain why `A-B-C-B` is a valid answer, but `B-C-B` isn't?

Comment: Yeah, I gave that some thought, and it makes practically zero sense.  Either I'm just not getting something that's actually really obvious, or your question and concept of what defines a set is flawed.  I'm inclined to believe this falls into the latter case ;p